# Understanding parts of JS code - Promise, resolve, reject, status

Tags: javascript, promise

I have cobbled together some JavaScript code from various sources, edited them and made it work.

The problem is, that I don't understand parts of the code, and I would like some help understanding those parts.

Basically what the code does is send the username and password to the hotspot, it waits 0,5 sec and sends the user input mail to the webserver.

What I have trouble understanding is `resolve("fast");`. Is fast inside reslove just becouse resolve needs an "argument/parameter", as it is never displayed?

Also, at some point my code got to...

```
                reject({
                    status: this.status,
                    statusText: xhr.statusText
                });
```

... and I got an error. Needless to say, I don't understand what and where exactly `status` and `statusText` should display.

Alot of the code I got from Stack Overflow and Developer.Mozilla.Org.

Thank you for the help.

*JS code*

```
document.getElementById("submit_ok").addEventListener("click", sendAjax);

function resolveAfter05Second() {
  console.log("starting fast promise")
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve("fast")
      console.log("fast promise is done")
    }, 500)
  })
}

async function sendAjax() {
    let ax1 = await Ajax1 ("POST", "http://router/login")
    let fast = await resolveAfter05Second()
    let ax2 = await Ajax2 ("POST", "http://webserver/anti-xss.php")
}

function Ajax1 (method, url){
    return new Promise (function (resolve,  reject){
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'http://router/login', true);
        xhr.onload = function(){
            if(this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300){
                resolve(xhr.response);
                console.log("Success!");
                console.log("You'r logged in.");
                console.log("XHR1 " + xhr.readyState);
                console.log("XHR1 " + xhr.status);
            }else{
                reject({
                    status: this.status,
                    statusText: xhr.statusText
                });
            }
        };
        xhr.onerror = function (){
            reject({
                status: this.status,
                statusText: xhr.statusText
            });
        };
        xhr.send("username=HSuser&password=SimpleUserPassword");
    });
}

function Ajax2 (method, url){
    return new Promise (function (resolve, reject){
        let xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr2.open('POST', 'http://webserver/anti-xss.php', true);
        xhr2.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr2.onload = function(){
            if(this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300){
                resolve(xhr2.response);
                console.log("Success!");
                console.log("You'r email is " + useremail + ".");
                console.log("XHR2 " + xhr2.readyState);
                console.log("XHR2 " + xhr2.status);
            }else{
                reject({
                    status: this.status,
                    statusText: xhr2.statusText
                });
            }
        };
        xhr2.onerror = function (){
            reject({
                status: this.status,
                statusText: this.statusText
            });
        };
        let useremail = document.getElementById("email").value;                 
        xhr2.send("Email="+encodeURIComponent(useremail));
    });
}
```

Comment: "*Is fast inside reslove just becouse resolve needs an "argument/parameter", as it is never displayed?*" it's more of self-documenting code. You can just call `resolve()` without parameters and it would work. Or you can call `resolve(3.14)` - it doesn't really matter if the value is never used. However, it's *possible* that you have something that does `promise.then(value => { if (value === "fast") { console.log("Zoom!") } })` which *will* use the value that the promise was resolved with.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read some articles about callbacks in node.js and how to handle them. A promise will basically give you ability to handle the code written in it  asynchronously.There are multiple ways to handle the callbacks.

You can write it like

```
Promise.then((data)=>{
    //this will be executed if and when promise resolves and will give you the data that you passed while resolving the promise
})
.catch((err)=>{
    //this will be executed if and when promise gets rejected and will give you the error that you passed while rejecting the promise
});
```

this is good for standing how promises works but is not a good approach in practice due to callback hell. I suggest that you study about callbacks and promises first and then use async/await after you understand the working of it.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. Any idea why `status` and `statusText` would throw an error? and what they should actually display?

Comment: Whenever you make a web request you if it is successful you will get a response in range from 200 - 299 it is a global standard any other code will indicate some error. Status For eg. 400-499 is for user error and 500-599 is for server error see: <https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/>. So, ideally if an API hit gets failed then you should return an error and reject the promise and statusText is supposed to have the information that tells you why the API failed in case of failure.

Comment: Ah, all right. But where would this be displayed? Shouldn't it be inside alert or console.log?  so Status would give me back 404 and StatusText would display not found.

Comment: It is just to pass an definitive error in the reject. Whenever someone will user the function and if it gets rejected they will get an object returned which will have two properties 'status' and 'statusText' so that they can figure out by looking at it that why the promise got rejected.

Comment: It is upto you how to handle the error you can return it to user i.e. in the case of API or you can print it on server using console

Comment: I think that covers everthing. Thanks for the help. =) 
 If I'll have any additional questions I'll ask a new question.

Comment: Sure, glad i could help.

Comment: Actually I have an additional question. Should I be using `status: this.status` or should I use `status: xhr2.status`?